# hide files With certain extension when mounting a directory

Tags: finder, ssh, mount

When working on a remote Linux desktop, I am often finding myself mounting the remote folder to look up the outputs on my mac:

```
umount -f /Volumes/somename
mkdir /Volumes/somename 
sshfs -o volname=somename -o follow_symlinks -o allow_other,defer_permissions me@server.name:/remote/path/ /Volumes/somename/
```

However, the (nested) directory includes aside of the results I want to look up (`*.pdf`) also a lot of files that I am not interested in (`*.root`). I would like to be able to hide those from views with finder completely - is it even possible to do?

I don't care about any files with `*.root` on my laptop so if there is a config that I could change system-wide that would be the simplest thing. But perhaps there is a way to do it when mounting the drive, to speed its loading time a little?

Comment: if the dmg is writable, you can run a combination of `find ` and `chflags hidden`  to hide all `*.root` files. Then set it as a function in zsh_profile & give the path to the dmg every time you have to run it

Comment: @ankii just tried out as a test after the mount to create a file `touch bla.root` and change its flag `chflags hidden bla.root` - but this had no effect. The remote machines use Linux - perhaps that's the reason?

Comment: oh I totally missed that you're working on a linux. you should check its man page then. And on Mac, it is followed by "killall Finder" or just close and reopen the window. Is there something that you forgot to refresh ?

Comment: Alternatively, rename them to start with `.` and they won't show up in finder without `cmd + shift + .`